# Why cannot I add my file to git?

Tags: git, github, terminal

Here is the code I've been working with in terminal:

```
macbook-2:blogger Robert$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/Robert/projects/flask_projects/blogger/.git/
macbook-2:blogger Robert$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
macbook-2:blogger Robert$ git add -A
macbook-2:blogger Robert$ ls
generator.py
macbook-2:blogger Robert$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: It looks like you are re-initializing your git repo. Can you run "git log" to see if generator.py was already added in a previous commit?

Comment: Has `generator.py` been modified since the last commit? If not, then `git add`ing it is pointless, and `git` will generally refuse to do so...

Comment: Should I modify the program and try to re-add it to git? I'm pretty sure in my trying to upload, I have already converted it to git but it still won't let me push it through.

Comment: See my answer...please note that "adding a file to git" is kind of ambigious... my answer is to verify that your file is being tracked.
If what you really mean is to have your file be pushed, than after you verify it is tracked, added, and committed, then push to your remote.

Comment: Jonathan- it looks like you were right! I typed git log and this came up: commit 11a9ee20f83d9756f6717286cb5ba9a0c813c9e2
Author: robschwartz <Robertschwar@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 28 22:28:06 2014 -0500
    Adding generator.py
How do I push it through?

Comment: That's great Rob. I appended to my answer below with the command you can use for pushing...

Comment: Junior programmer problems: I forgot to add new repo...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your file is already tracked in your repository.
Due to the message `Reinitialized existing Git repository in...` it seems the confusion here is that you have already initialized your Git repo.

To verify that `generator.py` has already been added to your repo, make sure it is being tracked by:

```
git ls-files generator.py --error-unmatch
```

If the output of that command is "generator.py" then the file is being tracked by Git and has been already added.

If the output is something like `error: pathspec 'generator.py' did not match any file(s) known to git` then your file is not yet being tracked. In this case, you can add it to your repo with `git add generator.py`.

To share your changes with the rest of your team, you will need to push.
If you are working on the `master` branch, execute this command:

```
git push origin master
```